# the "Select all" header checkbox in django 2.7.6 version?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-actions

[image]

How to get header checkbox in python version 2.7.6?

Comment: You should provide some source code for your question first.

Comment: it is the django admin panel.